# Is it bad form to count on exceptions?

Tags: python, exception

My current situation is involved in making a game in python using a library called pygame. I have a method called getTile() that returns the tile every time the player moves. The lvlDict makes up the world.

```
def getTile(self, pos):
    x = pos[0]
    y = pos[1]
    return self.lvlDict[x,y].kind
```

and i'm thinking about changing it to this

```
def getTile(self, pos):
    try:
        x = pos[0]
        y = pos[1]
        return self.lvlDict[x,y].kind
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

where there would be some interpretation for what to do if it were None. Likely just move back to where it previously was. Is this inherently bad or acceptable?
Even if it's just a matter of opinion, I'd like to know what people think about it.

Comment: Well, you could also use the `get` method which allows using a default value if the key is not present. Together with the null-object pattern you also don't need to handle `None`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exceptions are slow so it's best to save them for truly exceptional circumstances. If it's an unexpected situation that doesn't normally crop up, then an exception is sensible. If an empty tile is a common occurrence it would be better to use an `if` check instead.

Another way to look at it is whether the user can trigger it or not. If the player can cause this condition merely by moving around the map, it probably shouldn't be an exception. Exceptions are more appropriate for when you encounter unexpected cases that aren't the user's fault, such as "oops, I forgot to put a wall here and the player wandered off the map" or "I expected this file to be there and it wasn't."

Comment: This is good correct, you will have to catch this exception _somewhere_ if it's going to affect the user experience. You may want to elaborate on  the remaining question _where should we catch the exception?_ ie. Catch it right here and handle `None` values everywhere vs catch it everywhere this function is called?

Comment: Well, if it is a truly exceptional condition that makes it a bad idea to continue, you can also catch the exception in a single place, in the main function.

Comment: Idiomatic Python favours EAFTP. Heck, even `for` loops use exceptions for termination. Exceptions also aren't that slow on CPython, at least not compared to other control flow.

Answer (score 11):

In this case, I think asking for forgiveness is better than asking for permission on the off chance that something happens to your dictionary between check and indexing, but in general, I tend to prefer not using exceptions for logic, entirely because exceptions are bloody slow.

```
In [1]: d = {i:i for i in xrange(10000)}

In [4]: def f(d):
    try:                     
        d["blue"]
    except KeyError:
        pass   

In [5]: def g(d):
    if "blue" in d: d["blue"]  

#Case: Key not in Dict

In [7]: timeit f(d)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 950 ns per loop

In [8]: timeit g(d)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 135 ns per loop

#Case: Key in Dict

In [9]: d["blue"] = 8 

In [10]: timeit f(d)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 151 ns per loop

In [11]: timeit f(d)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 151 ns per loop
```

Comment: As clarification: I don't think using exceptions as logic is terrible in the way that using input in python2 is almost always terrible, but it's also not a good idea. Probably a "think twice before you do this", but not "go get the pope's signature first"

Comment: Your timing is broken - you run `timeit f(d)` twice in the second case making it seem like `if` is equally fast (it's not). The time you give is tiny anyway (for CPython). Making decisions like this from broken nanobenchmarks is silly. The difference is even smaller on PyPy, which you should be using already if such speed differences trouble you.

Comment: FWIW, Knupp wrote an interesting blog post on this: https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/ Personally, I found using exceptions mostly difficult because of pre-learned notions coming from Java as to how they work under the hood.

Answer (score 7):

Although it is true that exceptions will often be slower than checking for possible failures that might occur, it is also most often not a difference that would matter in practical applications. In particular, it is usually not a significant difference for applications for which Python is used as the language of choice. Therefore, as the Python glossary for EAFP explains:

> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python
>   coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and
>   catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast
>   style is characterized by the presence of many try and except
>   statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many
>   other languages such as C.

Indeed, it is common in Python to employ exceptions (and ask for forgiveness) to handle errors, even if those errors are expected to occur often and on a regular basis.

Now, in your particular case it seems equally elegant to simply check if key is in a dictionary (as suggested by other answers). Still, you should not be afraid to use exceptions and their use (even for expected) error handling is totally Pythonic.

Answer (score 3):

Using exceptions to implement normal flow through your code is not bad form in python. Such an approach is used by some language constructions including generators, which signal no more elements by raising `StopIteration`.

Other answers have pointed out that relying on the exception may make the code slower, and not relying on it may introduce a race condition. You can avoid both problems by using both an `if` construction and an `except` block. But that introduces another problem in that it makes your code more complicated and thus more error prone.

I would say that correctness is in general more important than performance (and if this piece of code was truly performance critical, you probably wouldn't write it in python to begin with). So if there is any possibility for the dict to change between checking for existence of the key and accessing it, I would definitely go with the exception. If you know such a race cannot happen, then I suggest you take the approach you find most readable.

There is another aspect of your code, which does appear to be bad form. Inside your `try` block I see three different places in which a `KeyError` could be raised. I am guessing you only intended to catch the exceptions from one of those places. By catching the exception from the other two locations it could be raised, you could make debugging the code harder. The condition triggering the bug would change from crashing with a descriptive trace to subtly incorrect behavior.

Thus only put those lines inside the try block, which really need to be there.

I am guessing this construction is closer to what you intended:

```
def getTile(self, pos):
    x = pos[0]
    y = pos[1]
    try:
        return self.lvlDict[x,y].kind
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

If you have a try block in which the first line could raise an exception, and the remaining lines are inside the try block because you don't want them to be executed in case of an exception, then you should be using a `try`-`except`-`else` construction.

Answer (score 1):

From a non-Python perspective, I would say that exceptions should used to handle invalid cases only, and ask the question: are we discussing a nominal case, an edge case, or a case of invalid input/result? If your "None" case is valid, but an edge case, I would say that it should be handled by program logic (do not throw an exception). If the "None" could happen, but really never should, then it should be handled by exception.

Not being familiar with Python, but assuming parallels with other programming environments e.g. C#:

- Wrapping code blocks with try/catches has negligible to nil performance impact; as soon as an exception is thrown, stuff happens behind the scenes which has a non-trivial performance cost.
- The prototypical case for throwing an exception is when you can't logically proceed from where you are, have to discard the current program state and find your way back to some earlier known state from which you can recover. That's what exception mechanisms are designed for, even if they find broader use.
- Used appropriately, exceptions help you write cleaner code by not cluttering with extra if-then logic, leaving only true "business" logic. They also get you away from awkward function signatures with cobbled-up return values for signaling error conditions. Used to excess, however, exceptions can end up hiding "business" logic, obfuscating your code.